# Shouldn't the distance be the same with and without toll costs?

Tags: here-api

Here's one (long) example route from Germany to Spain:

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?
jsonAttributes=41
&waypoint0=53.94499,10.85676
&waypoint1=41.59747,-4.72606
&currency=EUR
&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled
&legAttributes=none
&trailerType=2
&trailersCount=1
&vehicleNumberAxles=3
&trailerNumberAxles=2
&tiresCount=10
&hybrid=0
&emissionType=6
&fuelType=diesel
&height=400cm
&trailerHeight=400cm
&length=1650cm
&width=255cm
&heightAbove1stAxle=100cm
&vehicleWeight=12000kg
&limitedWeight=40000kg
&commercial=1
&driver_cost=1000
&vehicle_cost=1
&app_id=
&app_code=
```

The total distance returned is 2121km.

When adding the tollVehicleType=3 parameter to make it calculate the toll costs, the total distance goes up by 113km to 2234km.

To disable toll cost optimization, the driver_cost is set to a high value and the vehicle_cost is set to a low value. This according to the documentation found here:
[calculation-considerations.html](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/calculation-considerations.html)

```
To only compute the toll cost along the fastest route (i.e. do not change the route to reduce toll cost) 
specify a high value in the driver_cost parameter and a low value in the vehicle_cost parameter.
```

But it doesn't seem to help, shouldn't the route distance be the same when calculating the route both with and without toll costs?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from Here support which did the trick:

> Kindly pass the parameter tollPass=transponder as well when
>   calculating route with toll cost, this would enable the routing
>   algorithm to consider routes which pass through a roads which, in HERE
>   data, are marked as "transponder-only". If this parameter is not
>   passed, the routing engine when using the toll calculation mode avoids
>   going through roads which are "transponder-only" adding to the
>   additional distance in the shared case.